# How is the UI of DADA-DADA.net built?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, design, css, ux-designer

[DADA-DADA.net](http://dada-data.net/)

How is the interface of this site built ? What's going on here ? Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For one I'm quite sure it depends a lot on http://pixijs.github.io/docs/index.html for all the interactivity.

Comment: Is the entire page manipulation done through pixie ???

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry for answering instead of commenting but I lack the reputation. 
I don't think I understand your question. What exactly you want to know?

As far I can see the website was build by front-end developer(s). It uses Node.js, socket.io, three.js for 3d rendering, TweenMax for the animation and navigation. Sites like this can be designed with tools like Just In Mind or most likely for this website, they used a video animation tool, like CINEMA 4D.

I hope I helped answer some of your questions

Comment: +1 It's a good answer (but the question is probably not suitable for this forum), and I hope you can get your reputation up soon :)